# "Syntax error:word unexpected(expecting ")" )" when installing Qt using a .run file

Tags: linux, qt

I tried to install Qt on Linux using a .run like this:

```
#sudo ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.0.run
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.0.run:1:./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.0.run:Syntax error:word unexpected(expecting")")
```

When did this, I got an error saying `Syntax error:word unexpected(expecting")")` and I tried `arm-linux-gcc-static` but failed.

I'm working on the Ubuntu 17.04, so I need the command on Debian.

How to install this `qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.6.0.run`?

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

Comment: some thing wrong with your .run file maybe file is corrupted check it with md5sum qt-opensource-linux~.run

Comment: check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)

Comment: It seems that your shell is trying to execute the binary as a shell script for some reason, where in fact it is an ELF executable (just have a look using, e.g. `hd` or just your favourite editor). Did you grant it the `x` right using `chmod`?